# Understanding the effect of arguments on .flatten method

Tags: ruby

The ruby doc does a great job of explaining what .flatten does without an argument. But I can't for the life of me understand what is happening when a 1 is passed to flatten

**`flatten(level) → new_ary`**

> Returns a new array that is a one-dimensional flattening of self (recursively).That is, for every element that is an array, extract its elements into the new array.The optional level argument determines the level of recursion to flatten.

```
s = [ 1, 2, 3 ]           #=> [1, 2, 3]
t = [ 4, 5, 6, [7, 8] ]   #=> [4, 5, 6, [7, 8]]
a = [ s, t, 9, 10 ]       #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, [7, 8]], 9, 10]
a.flatten                 #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
a = [ 1, 2, [3, [4, 5] ] ]
a.flatten(1)              #=> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

By 'recursion' does it mean that the argument directly effects the number of actions '.flatten' performs to convert the multidimensional array to a regular singular array? Terms that a super-scrub can understand would be greatly appreciated here.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of recursion? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). It is essential programming knowledge.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev   No I am not. Are there any resources that demonstrate the concept of recursion within a ruby environment?

Comment: There's nothing special about recursion in ruby. It's the same principle everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, argument to `flatten` means how deep should go in attempts to flatten the structure.

```
a = [ 1, 2, [3, [4, 5] ] ]

# where
[ 1, 2, [3, [4, 5] ] ] # level 0 (original array)
[3, [4, 5] ]           # level 1
[4, 5]                 # level 2
```

So, if you pass 1, it will go only one level deep and will treat level-2 array as a single element and will not recurse into it. So,

```
a.flatten(1)              #=> [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

What [@Sergio Tulentsev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431190/understanding-the-effect-of-arguments-on-flatten-method/21431288#21431288) mentioned in his answer, are correct. But one more thing I would like to add here -

*if you don't supply any argument, then **flattening** will be happened recursively, in all nested level*. That is `a.flatten` will give `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Don't think `a.flatten` is same as `a.flatten(0)`. No, they work differently. If you pass nested level number as `0`,`1`,`2`, then *flattening* will be happened as you asked the method to do. But If you don't pass any argument, the method will work, as it is designed to do, i.e it will create a single level array, by breaking all the deeper nested one also.

```
a = [ 1, 2, [3, [4, [5,[6]]] ] ]
# see no nested level is here, all are flattened.
a.flatten # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```